# Android Studio files relocation

Tags: android, file, android-studio

Hey I have a hard time setting up this program.

I have a SSD directory (C:) with only 57 gigs of room. Now when I use AndroidStudio the program makes files inside my C: drive. I have 0MBs left on that drive so I tried to relocate them to my D: drive, which has like 800 gigs of room. I have read several things about changing stuff in the Evironment Variables in Control Panel. But it doesn't seem to work. Whenever I start up AndroidStudio the program keeps making the new files inside my C: drive, which is full, so i can't start building my app.

Please explain to me (like im 5) how to relocate those 3 files (.android, .AndroidStudios and .gradle) and how to tell the computer to not make any files inside C:.

Comment: I don't think the Android Studio consumes that a lot of gigs but the Android SDK does. You can download the Android SDK separately and place it in your `D:` by extracting it. In your A.S. goto **File > Settings > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK** and replace the Android SDK location.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment :) .. I have set up my SDK just fine, it's located in the D: drive.

I have literally 0MBs/KBs left on my C: drive so every file that added into the cache of .android, .androidstudio and .gradle is too much. So I need to relocate those 3 files, my SDK is set up fine :)

Comment: Oh now my SDK is suddenly causing problems. I can't even start Android Studio because of it, so i can't replace the Android SDK location

Comment: Even if this particular task is possible, your system is not going to function properly with 0KB of free space on the C drive.  Windows just isn't going to deal well with that.  I think you're going to have to free up some space either way.

Comment: Yeah I know, the C: drive is very small... If I can relocate the files mentioned above it will safe me a few gigs of space.

@Enzokie I have tried that before.

Update: My SDK and .gradle files seemed to have relocated. I just have 2 files left to relocate: .androidstudio2.3 and .android. I've set the path into my D: drive but even then he still makes new files in my C: drive, and I dont want that. I edited the ideas.properties file inside my AndroidStudio installation folder, but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I just can't get it to work. Please help. I set my SDK to my D: drive, and at one point it all worked fine. Was about to start making an app when suddenly Android Studio crashes ("qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working") ... I have no idea what is going wrong.